# Render component in Drawer with Material-ui Lists

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This feels like it should be self-explanatory in the Docs, but they abstract out a key part of the List code to another file and don't show it. So, I'm left asking you fine folks.

I'm looking to do something pretty simple: Use a List-based sidebar with Material-ui (beta-version) to render a component in a Drawer. I have the list setup, but I can't figure out how to make the ListItems link to the components and perform the render. Here's my code:

```
class DashboardScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={this.props.classes.container}>
            <Appbar pagetitle="Dashboard" />
            <div className={this.props.classes.appFrame}>
                <Drawer
                    type="permanent"
                    classes={{
                        paper: this.props.classes.drawerPaper,
                    }}
                    anchor="left">
                    <div className={this.props.classes.drawerHeader} />
                    <List>
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <AssessmentIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Analytics"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <ImportContactsIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Create Investigation"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <AssignmentIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Create Survey"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <AssignmentTurnedInIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Create Response"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <SettingsIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Settings"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                    </List>
                </Drawer>
                <main className={this.props.classes.content}>
                    Testing Stuff!
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

What I'm rendering is just another separate component called "Analytics". There's nothing special about it. How do I get the first ListItem, with text = "Analytics", render said component `<Analytics />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Here's my code:

```
class DashboardScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={this.props.classes.container}>
            <Appbar pagetitle="Dashboard" />
            <div className={this.props.classes.appFrame}>
                <Drawer
                    type="permanent"
                    classes={{
                        paper: this.props.classes.drawerPaper,
                    }}
                    anchor="left">
                    <div className={this.props.classes.drawerHeader} />
                    <List>
                        <ListItem button component={({...props}) => <Link to={this.props.match.url + '/analytics'} {...props} />}>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <AssessmentIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Analytics"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <ImportContactsIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Create Investigation"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <AssignmentIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Create Survey"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <AssignmentTurnedInIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Create Response"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                        <ListItem button>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                <SettingsIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary="Settings"/>
                        </ListItem> 
                    </List>
                </Drawer>
                <main className={this.props.classes.content}>
                    <Route path={this.props.match.url + "/analytics"} component={Analytics}/>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Essentially, you need to contain the Route for the component within the main section of the Drawer. Then, you need to Link to that route via the  component wrapped within the component prop on the ListItem.

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

The `ListItem` will have an `onClick` property that it propagates through to the appropriate child components. So, if you're searching to receive clicks for each `ListItem`, you can simply do this:

```
<ListItem button onClick={() => alert("Hey buddy this will alert when clicked.")}>
    <ListItemIcon>
          <AssessmentIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <Analytics />
</ListItem>
<ListItem button onClick={() => alert("This is a click on a different item.")}>
    <ListItemIcon>
          <ImportContactsIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <Analytics />
</ListItem>
```

The propagation of props down to the appropriate area is described at the bottom of the props section on the [`ListItem` API page](https://material-ui-next.com/api/list-item/).

Comment: Very useful. Thank you much. I think the right call for me is to use the component prop, and then a Link, but I'm not sure. Any idea how to get the Link to render in a Drawer?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to simply change ListItemText with your custom component?

```
<ListItem button>
    <ListItemIcon>
          <AssessmentIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <Analytics />
</ListItem>
```

Comment: I did not. Although I'll admit, I'm very skeptical about that - the ListItemText is supposed to be there, to display the text associated with the Button (the ListItem), much like a button would have text associated with it. What I'm asking is more akin to how a button has an onClick method, that perhaps renders a component, or something like that I'm not sure.